# How do I get rid of mayonnaise smell?

Tags: mayonnaise, smell

Today for the first time, I tested classic egg mayonnaise.
All I can say that it smelled strongly like yeast!

Is there a way to get rid of that smell? Do mayonnaise in general have that smell?

Enlighten please.

Comment: Can you post something of your recipe (at least the ingredients)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strongest smells in mayonnaise should be vinegar and egg. There shouldn't be any yeast, and therefore any yeast smell, so that is a bit concerning. I am not sure what might imitate a yeast smell.

I don't know how to counter the smell since I am not sure what the origination of the smell is. Does it taste okay? Is the texture okay? I do find that homemade and store brand mayonnaises have pretty different smells in general.

Comment: I agree; I have never found a mayonnaise that smelled of yeast, both in Italy and USA.

Comment: Katey, thanks, perhaps you are right, I am confusing the smell of vinegar with yeast. I smelled vinegar yesterday, and it smelled exactly like the mayonnaise.

Comment: In that case it's probably that the ratio was off or you didn't get it to emulsify completely and the mayonnaise cracked. Keep experimenting!

Comment: I didn't experiment anything, I purchased it from the market.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, mayonnaise smells like mayonnaise. I can't distinguish store bought from homemade by smell. It should be smelling more like vinegar, so maybe the brand you are using has a yeasty component.

Comment: Thanks it was vinegar's smell which I was finding confusing